# Double union notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

The Cantor set $C$ is defined as

$$C= [0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=0}^{3^n-1} \left ( \frac{3k+1}{3^{n+1}},\frac{3k+2}{3^{n+1}} \right )
$$

Does the double union of sets work like the double summation?

I start counting from $n=0$ and then all of the $k$'s.

I.e.

For $n=0...0$, $k$ goes from 0 to 0

$$\bigcup_{n=0}^{0} \bigcup_{k=0}^{0} = \left ( \frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3} \right )$$

$\\$

For $n=1$, $k=0...2$

$$ \bigcup_{n=0}^{1} \bigcup_{k=0}^{2} = \left ( \frac {1}{3}, \frac {2}{3} \right)
\cup \left ( \frac {3 \cdot 0+1}{3^{1+1}}, \frac {3 \cdot 0+2}{3^{1+1}} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {3 \cdot 1+1}{3^{1+1}}, \frac {3 \cdot 1+2}{3^{1+1}} \right)  \cup \left ( \frac {3 \cdot 2+1}{3^{1+1}}, \frac {3 \cdot 2+2}{3^{1+1}} \right)= \left ( \frac {1}{3}, \frac {2}{3} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {1}{9}, \frac {2}{9} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {4}{9}, \frac {5}{9} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {7}{9}, \frac {8}{9} \right) = \\ \left ( \frac {1}{3}, \frac {2}{3} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {1}{9}, \frac {2}{9} \right)  \cup \left ( \frac {7}{9}, \frac {8}{9} \right)  $$
$\\$

For $n=2$, $k=0...8$

$$ \bigcup_{n=0}^{2} \bigcup_{k=0}^{8} = \left ( \frac {1}{3}, \frac {2}{3} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {1}{9}, \frac {2}{9} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {7}{9}, \frac {8}{9} \right) 
\cup \left ( \frac {3 \cdot0 +1}{3^{2+1}}, \frac {3 \cdot 0+2}{3^{2+1}} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {3 \cdot 1+1}{3^{2+1}}, \frac {3 \cdot 1+2}{3^{2+1}} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {3 \cdot 2+1}{3^{2+1}}, \frac {3 \cdot 2+2}{3^{2+1}} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {3 \cdot 3+1}{3^{2+1}}, \frac {3 \cdot 3+2}{3^{2+1}} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {3 \cdot 4+1}{3^{2+1}}, \frac {3 \cdot 4+2}{3^{2+1}} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {3 \cdot 5+1}{3^{2+1}}, \frac {3 \cdot 5+2}{3^{2+1}} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {3 \cdot 6+1}{3^{2+1}}, \frac {3 \cdot 6+2}{3^{2+1}} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {3 \cdot 7+1}{3^{2+1}}, \frac {3 \cdot 7+2}{3^{2+1}} \right) \ \left ( \frac {3 \cdot 8+1}{3^{2+1}}, \frac {3 \cdot 8+2}{3^{2+1}} \right)= $$

$\\$

$$\left ( \frac {1}{3}, \frac {2}{3} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {1}{9}, \frac {2}{9} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {7}{9}, \frac {8}{9} \right) \cup \left (\frac{1}{27},\frac{2}{27} \right) \cup \left (\frac{4}{27},\frac{5}{27} \right) \cup \left (\frac{7}{27},\frac{8}{27} \right) \cup \left (\frac{10}{27},\frac{11}{27} \right) \cup \left (\frac{13}{27},\frac{14}{27} \right) \cup \left (\frac{16}{27},\frac{17}{27} \right)\cup \left (\frac{19}{27},\frac{20}{27} \right)\cup \left (\frac{22}{27},\frac{23}{27} \right) \cup \left (\frac{25}{27},\frac{26}{27} \right)= $$

$\\$

$$\left ( \frac {1}{3}, \frac {2}{3} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {1}{9}, \frac {2}{9} \right) \cup \left ( \frac {7}{9}, \frac {8}{9} \right) \cup \left (\frac{1}{27},\frac{2}{27} \right) \cup \left (\frac{7}{27},\frac{8}{27} \right) \cup   \left (\frac{19}{27},\frac{20}{27} \right)  \cup \left (\frac{25}{27},\frac{26}{27} \right) $$

$\\$

For $n=3$, $k=0...26$

.
.
.

Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the  Middle Third Cantor set  $$C= [0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=0}^{3^n-1} \left ( \frac{3k+1}{3^{n+1}},\frac{3k+2}{3^{n+1}} \right )$$
is constructive and what you have done is correct.
You have demonstrated the first three steps clearly.

The fractal nature of the Cantor set becomes more and more evident as you find the double union for larger value of $n$

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if $a,b\in\Bbb Z\cup\{\pm\infty\}$,
$$ \bigcup_{n=a}^bA_n=\{\,x\mid \exists n\in\Bbb Z\colon a\le n\le b\land x\in A_n\,\}
$$
Thus if additionally $f,n\colon\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$,
$$ \bigcup_{n=a}^b\bigcup_{k=f(n)}^{g(n)}B_{n,k}=\{\,x\mid \exists n, k\in\Bbb Z\colon a\le n\le b\land f(n)\le k\le g(n)\land x\in B_{n,k}\,\}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your replay. My knowledge about set theory is basic, and I have some trouble understanding your answer. The method I used in the question, is it right?